# asymmetric violin plots or back-to-back density plots in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot an asymmetric violin plot to compare two violin plots (i guess this is basically just two kernel density estimate plots back to back).  Is there a way to do this with the vanilla violin plotting tools of R?

I know I can create a single density plot like this:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
d <- density(x)
plot(d)
```

and I know that `density` returns the `x` and `y` components of the density estimation, but I can't seem to put the pieces together.

Comment: Can you provide some code for what you already have. Its easier for the community to help if you provide an example.

Answer (score 6):

I would just use `density` for this, and it should work all right. I don't think you gain very much by doing things "violin" style, mirrored across the 0 line. Personally I think the comparison is much easier on top of each other.

```
a <- rnorm(20)
b <- rnorm(50)


ad <- density(a)
bd <- density(b)

abd <- list(x = c(ad$x, bd$x),
            y = c(ad$y, bd$y))

# "violin" style comparison (psuedo-mirrored), switch x and y to make vertical.
plot(range(abd$x), c(-max(abd$y), max(abd$y)), type = "n")
lines(ad$x, ad$y, type = "l")
lines(bd$x, -bd$y, type = "l")
abline(h = 0)

# on top of each other comparison, would nicely generalize for more distributions
plot(range(abd$x), range(abd$y), type = "n")
lines(ad)
lines(bd)
```

Comment: Nice. I was sure I'd be able to find a duplicate for this, but I couldn't find anything even terribly close. (Well, same thing for histograms, but that's still pretty different.)